# Anroid - Activities and Dialogs do not open from com.android.settings.SubSettings Activity

Tags: android, accessibility, android-permissions, xiaomi

I'm testing my Android app on a Xiaomi Mi 9T Android 10 API 29.

The process is as follows:

In my Accessibility Activity, I start the Accessibility System Intent

The intent open the Settings Activity and I need to dive 2 more Subsettings until I can enable the permission

In my Accessibility Activity there is a timer that keeps monitoring until the permission is granted:

```
public void timerStart() {
    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
                Accessibility.this.timer.cancel();
                
                //Execution passes through here, but ActivityB never starts
                Intent intent = new Intent(Accessibility.this, ActivityB.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}
```

I did a test. I also tried opening a Dialog instead of an Activity, but nothing happens either.

```
public void timerStart() {
    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
                Accessibility.this.timer.cancel();
                
                //Execution passes through here, but the Dialog is never opened
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(Accessibility.this)
                                .setMessage("Teste")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    }})
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                
                return;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}
```

I did one more test. I ran the code below inside the timer's run method and verified that the top Activity is com.android.settings.SubSettings.
So it concludes that I can't start anything from SubSettings

```
public void timerStart() {
    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
                Accessibility.this.timer.cancel();
                
                ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(0);
                for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info : taskList) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "############################################");
                    Log.i(TAG, "info.numActivities: " + info.numActivities);
                    Log.i(TAG, "info.numActivities: " + info.numActivities);
                    Log.i(TAG, "info.baseActivity: " + info.baseActivity.getClassName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "info.topActivity: " + info.topActivity.getClassName());
                }
                
                return;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}
```

Console output:

```
I/Accessibility: ############################################
I/Accessibility: info.numActivities: 4
I/Accessibility: info.baseActivity: com.myapp.android.activity.Accessibility
I/Accessibility: info.topActivity: com.android.settings.SubSettings
I/Accessibility: ############################################
I/Accessibility: info.numActivities: 1
I/Accessibility: info.baseActivity: com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher
I/Accessibility: info.topActivity: com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher
```

What could be happening inside the timer's run method, which is preventing any Activity or any Dialog from opening?

Thanks a lot